# Which python to use on Enterprise Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, python

I'm currently learning python and I recently bought a book that goes through Python 3. Where I work we use Red Hat Enterprise Linux, and I've noticed that on RHEL 5 and RHEL 6 the versions of python are 2.4 and 2.6 respectively.

Obviously an enterprise-grade distro like Red Hat is cautious to include upstream packages, but is it any use for me to learn a version of python that is not included in the distro?

If so, what's the convention of installing python 3 on Red Hat and using that version for programs I develop? I would think I would not want to break the current version of python installed in /usr/bin because of the dependencies, so would convention be for me to install python 3 from source into /usr/local/bin? Or where else would I put it?

Any thoughts/comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Python 3 alongside 2 as long as it's configured to a different folder. Then it's just a matter of pointing your scripts to the proper install of python.

For reference: http://www.hosting.com/support/linux/installing-python-3-on-centosredhat-5x-from-source

Comment: I do believe that by default, the interpreter invoked for python 3 is different as well. It shouldn't break anything, unless someone, rather ill-advicedly decided to uninstall python 2. Its probably also useful to look at things like virtualenv for this

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't uninstall 2 because Yum itself requires it...what a headache that would bring. :-)

Comment: People do that. Its potentially painful ;p

Answer (score 1):

I think that [python.org](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) has this covered quite nicely on their wiki.

For most part, python 2 is feature frozen, but should be supported for quite a while. A lot of stuff relies on it, and some major software needs it. Python 2 is the status quo, and you are VERY likely to find this on almost any major distro.

Python 3 has a lot of new shiny stuff, and a syntax that's similar enough to work out how to migrate between them. I've learnt python 3, and for simpler stuff, there's no significant difference. *Some* stuff works differently. Python 3 is  *the future*. You have nothing to lose by learning this.

I'd say, learn both!

More importantly tho, they are designed to run side by side - you select which one to run by the command interpreter selection on your scripts. `#!python` or `#!python2` will invoke python2. Using `#!python3` will let you run python 3 scripts.